# Why do we need 2 entry points in server-side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am exploring server-side rendering of React using Dot Net. I found out that we need 2 separate JS files for server-side rendering. One for client side and one for server side. I don't understand the reason.

Comment: Usually app needs to support code splitting so for server you build one file without code splitting and chunks for client.
Another reason is to have different entry files with your router as server needs `StaticRouter` and client usually requires `BrowserRouter`.
In server you also need to pass values collected from the server, in client you dont need that.

Comment: Didn't understand it clearly. Can you please guide me where I could find the relevant stuff to understand it. Perhaps with an example

Answer (score 0):

1-we want to make sure that we never ever import any server side code into any file that will be eventually sent out to the browser. the reason for that, we might mistakenly leak an API key or some very sensitive data.

2-In client-side and server-side routing is handled differently. We will use the StaticRouter on the server. It is specifically made for use on the server side rendering. When we do the initial render of the app, it is going to be using the static router. When our application gets shipped down to the browser and it gets rendered a second time or hydrated on the browser, we will swap out to using the browserRouter instead. Browser router has the ability to look at the URL but StaticRouter needs to be told manually.

```
 import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";

 <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={{}}>
```

3-configuration of redux is different. In server side, before we ship down our pages to browser, we need to make sure all the data fetch is complete, our components gets its data to be rendered.

4-By keeping client-side and server-side code separate, in the future we can switch our front-end framework or server-side easily.